# Pinning icons to top of the vertical flexbox bar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have 3 vertical flexbox bars with different height and I'd like to place 3 different icons on the top of 3 vertical bars.

I tried by using margin and padding to fix the icons at the top of the flexbox but when i switch the window to responsive mode then again icons moves to different places.

**Here is an image of how i wanted:**

[image]

**Here's an image of how i am getting like:**

[image]

**My HTML Code:**

```
<div>
       <div className="prize">
            <div class="prizeimage2">
                <img src={prizeTwo} alt="2ndprizeicon"/>
            </div>
            <div class="prizeimage1">
                <img src={prizeOne} alt="1stprizeicon"/>
            </div>
            <div class="prizeimage3">
                <img src={prizeThree} alt="3rdprizeicon"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div className="container">
        <div class="item item1">
           <p className="hourstext">28<br></br> hrs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item item2">
           <p className="hourstext">25<br></br> hrs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item item3">
           <p className="hourstext">30<br></br> hrs</p>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;

    background: #162983;
}

.prize{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.item { 
    width: 75px;
    background: #8C9CE7; 
}

.item1 {
    height: 35%;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.item2 {
    height: 45%;
    margin-left: 9px;
} 

.item3 {
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


.prizeimage1 {
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    
}

.prizeimage2 {
    padding-top: 45px;

}

.prizeimage3 {
    padding-top: 190px;

}
```

Comment: i can't see your media queries in your CSS, did you wrote some? if not add Media Queries and design the responsive view

Comment: @Ctac, i haven't added media queries, is there any other way to fixed it on the top of vertical bar ?

Comment: if your code works on Desktop size, but not responsive , you need to design it with Media Queries for the certain screen size. Maybe this will help you - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I am actually designing it in mobile version and the vertical flexbox bar code is working fine with Android mobile dimensions but when i change the dimensions in the chrome dev tool then the icons are getting misplaced.